# Can a "Rest" Operator Get Written in Javascript which Doesn't use Iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Lisps that I've seen there usually exists a 'rest' operator which returns all elements of a list in the same order, without the 0th element of that list.  Without using iteration (no for or while loops), and without iteration happening via some other function or method does there exist a way to create a similar rest operator in Javascript?

For example, rest([1, 2, 3]) should return [2, 3], and rest([10, 2, 6]) should return [2, 6], and in general where 'arr' is the passed in array rest([arr[0], ..., arr[n]]) should return [arr[1], ..., arr[n]].

I had the idea of having a default value of 0 for a hidden 'counter' parameter of rest, but what I have below doesn't quite work:

```
function rest(arr, counter = 0) 
{
  if (counter === arr.length)
{
  return [];
}
  else
    {
      rest(arr, counter + 1)[0] = arr[counter]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `arr.slice(1)`?

Comment: “without iteration happening via some other function or method” isn’t going to happen. JavaScript arrays aren’t linked lists.

Comment: @sloth How does 'slice' work 'underneath the hood'?  Does it use iteration?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Yes of course it does. There is no way to do what you know from lisp, as JavaScript arrays are not linked lists - you can't get the tail in an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @dougspoonwood That depends in how it's implemented in the runtime you care about. Not all are open source, but those that are you could check yourself. Also, it depends on how deep you wanna dig. Do you care about iteration in Javascript itself? The bytecode thats generated by the Javascript source?  Iteration in your Javascript runtime implementation?

Comment: @sloth Thanks for your comment, and for the questions that you've suggested I consider.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can use rest syntax of [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring). As from Docs:

> When destructuring an array, you can unpack and assign the remaining part of it to a variable using the rest pattern:

**Demo:**

```js
let rest = (arr) => {
  let [first, ...rest] = arr;
  return rest;
};

console.log(rest([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(rest([10, 5, 6]));
```

Comment: How does that work 'underneath the hood', so to speak?  Does it "... rest" use iteration?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Yes, it creates a new array and copies the remaining entries from the iterator.